# Get last two entries of each account in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got script that gives me all transactions for day for all accounts and sub accounts. His return you can see on the image. What I want, is return result as two last transactions for each accountId and subaccountId. Ideal return would be:

```
 AccountId| SubAccountId| AmountInDay | Date   
---------------------------------------------
 210      | 1           |  0.00       |2017-06-20 00:00:00.000
 210      | 1           |  0.00       |2017-06-05 00:00:00.000
 1234     | 1           |  0.00       |2017-06-20 00:00:00.000
 1234     | 1           |  0.00       |2017-06-05 00:00:00.000
```

This is the code of my script:

```
with CTE1 as
(
select top 2 AccountId, SubAccountId, [Date], sum(Amount_Amount) as Amount
from dbo.PayoutInstallment
group by accountId, SubAccountId, [Date]

)
, CTE2 as
(
select AccountId,SubAccountId, Amount_Amount, [Date],
       dense_rank() over (partition by AccountId order by [Date] desc) as rn
from dbo.PayoutInstallment
)
select a1.AccountId,a1.SubAccountId, Sum(a1.Amount_Amount) as AmountInDay, a1.[Date]
from CTE2 a1
left join CTE2 a2
on a1.AccountId = a2.AccountId and a1.[Date] > a2.[Date]
and a2.rn = a1.rn+1
group by a1.[Date], a1.AccountId, a1.SubAccountId
order by a1.[Date] desc
```

[image: Image of return]

**EDIT**
 Sample Data

```
 AccountId| SubAccountId| AmountInDay | Date   
---------------------------------------------
 210      | 1           |  0.00       |2017-03-15 00:00:00.000
 210      | 1           |  0.00       |2017-04-20 00:00:00.000
 210      | 1           |  100.00     |2017-05-17 00:00:00.000
 210      | 1           |  1.00       |2017-06-05 00:00:00.000
 210      | 1           |  1.00       |2017-06-05 00:00:00.000
 1234     | 1           |  0.00       |2017-06-05 00:00:00.000
 1234     | 1           |  0.00       |2017-06-05 00:00:00.000
 1234     | 1           |  1.00       |2017-06-10 00:00:00.000
 1234     | 1           |  1.00       |2017-04-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: I want different output. Not sum of transactions from all days, but sum of transactions from last 2 days, when transactions have been made.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy He post the desire output. But without source data we cant know what was the process.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use row_number and get 2 records as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select AccountId, SubAccountId, [Date], sum(Amount_Amount) over (partition by accountid, SubAccountId, [Date])
        ,RowN = Row_number() over (partition by accountid, SubAccountId, [Date] order by [date] desc)
    from dbo.PayoutInstallment
) a where a.RowN <= 2
```

Comment: I dont think you need partition by date if you only want last two transaction. Parition By Date will give last two of each date if there is some time involve. But looks like isnt the case.

Answer (score 0):

Assume one day one transaction,

```
;WITH cte AS(SELECT *
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountId, SubAccountId ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS Rownum
              FROM PayoutInstallment
 )
 SELECT *
      , SUM(AmountInDay) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountId, SubAccountId) AS SumLast2days
FROM cte
WHERE Rownum<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `SUM` for the last two day you need to assign a number to each day. Then bring all the data related to those days by `JOIN` both dataset and then perform a `GROUP BY`

```
WITH cte as (
     SELECT AccountId, SubAccountId, [Date],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountId, SubAccountId 
                               ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn
     FROM dbo.PayoutInstallment
)
SELECT P.AccountId, 
       P.SubAccountId,
       P.[Date],
       SUM(ammount)
FROM dbo.PayoutInstallment P
JOIN cte C
  ON P.[Date] = C.[Date]
 AND P.AccountId  =  C.AccountId
 AND P.SubAccountId  = C.SubAccountId
WHERE rn <= 2  -- Just the last day of each account, subacount
GROUP BY P.AccountId, 
         P.SubAccountId,
         P.[Date]
```

Comment: I do have multiple transactions on the one day. I use Sum() to count sum of the day for each account

Comment: I see, the transaction have time? Do you want the last two transaction of each day or the last two transaction in general? Because if all have same time we cant decide which one are the last two. Or you want the sum of all transactions for the last `two days`?

Comment: No, transactions don't have time. I want last sum of transactions from last two days when they have been made, For example, I have multiple transactions on 5th of may, 25th of may and 1st of june. I want to select sum of transactions from 25-th of may and 1st of june.

Comment: Check EDIT answer

Comment: hm, it only shows sum of transactions for the last day when the occured. How display sum of transactions for day when they occured before?

Comment: Post sample data and expected result. You have to gimme something to work with. Does the cte filter the last two dates correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147181/discussion-between---and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `GROUP BY`, so if you want the results to be sorted after the grouping, you should use `HAVING` if you want otherwise you should use WHERE. Here is an example of a `WHERE` clause you can use in your query to get only results between the last two days.

```
WHERE (a1.[Date] BETWEEN GETDATE()AND GETDATE()-2)
```